# Comparing Two Lists of Tuples in Swift for duplicates

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I'll preface by saying that i'm using Swift 1.2. I'm currently working on a breadth first search algorithm which I've implemented before in other languages such as javaScript or python.

Generally, when im coding BFS, I like to have three things a queue, visited nodes, and a temporary walkable nodes. Each iteration i form possible walkable nodes with the current evaluated node. In order to avoid duplicates in my visited and queue lists I compare my visited (which keeps track of every single node that was ever visited) to walkable

I currently have the queue working correctly and I've debugged and come to the conclusion that my messy implementation of finding duplicates between visited array of tuples and walkable array of tuples is not working correctly.

Really all im asking for is for an elegant way to find duplicates between these two...

```
var visited: [(x: Int, y: Int)] = []
var Walkable = checkForWalkable(gridFile, Eval) // returns list of tuples that are walkable 

outputs:
Checked for walkable: [(28, 22), (27, 21), (28, 20), (29, 21)]
visited: [(28, 22), (28, 23), (27, 22), (28, 21), (29, 22), (28, 24),(27, 23), (29, 23), (26, 22), (27, 21)]     
New List: [(27, 21), (29, 21)]
Current Queue: [(28, 21), (29, 22), (28, 24), (27, 23), (29, 23), (26, 22), (27, 21), (27, 21), (29, 21)]
```

The new list above represents new nodes that capable of being added (aren't duplicates) The problem is... that duplicated do get added.
Here's my messy code:

```
func findUniqeTuples(A: [(x:Int,y:Int)], B: [(Int,Int)]) ->  [(Int,Int)] {

var indexArray:[Int] = []

for element in A { // visited

    var count = 0

    for items in B { // walkable

        if element.0 == items.0  && element.1 == items.1{

            indexArray.append(count)

        }
        count++

    } // end for

}// end for

var array = B
for i in indexArray{
   array.removeAtIndex(i)
}

return array
}
```

Comment: Just put one list into a set, and check the elements of the other list whether they are in the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are removing elements with indices by random order. Removing a preceding element causes to shift the rest of elements to be removed so the indices indicate to wrong elements. The following will work for you.

```
for (i, e) in enumerate(B) {
    for items in A {
        if e.0 == items.0 && e.1 == items.1 {
            indexArray.append(i)
        }
    }
}
var array = B
for i in reverse(indexArray) {
    array.removeAtIndex(i)
}
```

In Swift 2.0, the `reverse` and `enumerate` both are now defined as methods, so it supposed to be:

```
for (i, e) in B.enumerate() { /* ... */ }
```

And

```
for i in indexArray.reverse() { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: So in swift, enumeration causes indexing in correct order? I wasn't aware of such functionality

Comment: `enumerate` generates indices in ascending order like `0, 1, 2, ...`. To solve the problem (removing causes the rest of elements to be shifted),  you have to remove elements in descending order so that the rest of indices are no longer affected by the element-shifting in the array, because that affects only the indices greater than the removed index. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Awesome I understand. Thank You. Great English!!